# Memory limitation of web apps on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, webkit, iphone-web-app

I have observed that heavy mobile apps tend to crash on mobile devices (be it IOS or Android)
Does web app have a max Memory limitation on mobile devices?
Is it per open tab Or for the overall browser (e.g. for Safari on IOS) ?
If yes, what is the limit ?

Answer (score -1):

The limit is define by the browser.
Depend of the cash limit calculate and fixed by the browser.
The limits depends of your memory, your free memory and your device specification.

Comment: Is there any specific limit for say Safari on IOS ?

Comment: Normaly no : depends of the device/soft and cache memory used by the user.